# javascript promises setTimeout

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

I'm currently working on a slot machine effect for a website. I use a function that calls itself several times with setTimeout(). I use setTimeout() and not a simple loop because I need the effect to slow down. This is where the milliseconds come in handy. After this i want to fire the same function with different parameters. So I need to know when the first "loop" is done. I tried promises for that. With no success.

To simplify the problem, can someone tell me why the code below doesn't fire the .then() method? I'm new to all this programming and this is my first question here. I hope it's not an obvious mistake I make here.

```
function countDown(i) {
  return promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

    console.log(i--);

    if (i > 0) {
      setTimeout( () => {
        countDown(i);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      resolve('counter finished:');
    }

  });

}

let counter = countDown(10);
counter.then( (msg) => {
  console.log(msg);
});
```

Comment: Because you have created 10 promises, and only waiting on the fist one that never gets resolved.

Comment: For a first question, I'd say it's pretty well-written. Welcome to SO!
As for the issue, Keith is right.

Comment: just a small hint: it will never end at exactly 10 seconds ;) it can even be 20 or more depending on the situation

Answer (score 10):

You simply need to resolve the promise after the recursive calls, like so:

```js
function countDown(i) {
  return promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

    console.log(i--);

    if (i > 0) {
      setTimeout( () => {
        countDown(i).then(resolve);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      resolve('counter finished:');
    }

  });

}

let counter = countDown(10);
counter.then( (msg) => {
  console.log(msg);
});
```

Comment: @Keith Yes, but then there would be no message attached, unless you did `resolve.bind(null, "counter finished")`, which I think ends up in more keystrokes

Comment: Before your edit, doing what i said it will still have said `"counter finished"`  try it..

Comment: @Keith Ah, gotcha. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into using `async` / `await`,  here is your example using this.

If you need to target old browser, you can also use something Babel / Typescript etc.  But most modern browser already support this.

```js
function sleep(ms) { return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms)) }

async function countDown(i) {
  while (i > 0) {
    console.log(i--);  
    await sleep(1000);
  }
  return "counter finished:";
}

let counter = countDown(10);
counter.then( (msg) => {
  console.log(msg);
});
```